# Should I clone servers for load balancing?

Tags: linux, proxy, load-balancing

[image]

For example, I want to design a structure similar to the photo above.

Let's say this is an e-commerce website. I need two or more application servers due to high traffic. Customers go through a proxy or loadbalancer before connecting to the servers directly. Then the proxy in between directs them to my servers. The real thing here is what I want to understand. I have two servers that will do the same job. Should they (server1 and server2) be duplicates of each other? How exactly should this structure be? Is it possible to prevent this duplication by adding another layer between proxy and server? I hope I could explain. If you have additional questions, you can ask them in the comments.

Comment: This depends a bit on the application itself. Not every app is built to handle this setup; one that relies on local file storage, for example, might break because the file you just uploaded is on the other server on the next pageview.

Comment: Your back-end servers don't have to be exact copies (they can each have a different hostname for example) but in an active-active setup  you normally want to ensure that making a request on back-end server 1 will always have the same results as making that same request on back-end server 2. For data stored in the shared database that is easy, but content that is normally stored in either a servers cache memory or on the local filesystem (file uploads and different session states for example) that may require adjustments to your application/infrastructure.

Comment: My reason for using two separate sever is to reduce the load on one of them. So, if one of my servers supports 10 thousand connections, I have a second server to prevent it from being disabled when 20 thousand people arrive.
All that require storage will be kept different from the servers. For example, I will use a separate storage for my photos.
These are two separate servers where only my code will be found